# LaTeX starts new page after using 'includegraphics'

Tags: chapters, include, includegraphics

I placed a picture in a new chapter but LaTeX puts it on a new page. But I want to have the picture under the topic of the chapter. My code looks like this:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Einleitung}
....Text....

\chapter{Local Positioning System}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{./LPS}
\caption{LPS - Schematische Darstellung}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I put some text under the `\end{figure}`, the text starts above the picture under the topic of the chapter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You ask LaTeX to put that picture wherever is enough space and probably there isn't on this page (you use the `figure` environment).

Comment: even if i scale the picture very smal latex puts it way under the topic chapter. so there should be enough place

Comment: Maybe you should simply remove the figure environment and use the `\captionof` macro instead of caption, because obviously you do not want your figure to float. But without having a compilable example (with documentclass and required packages) it's hard to give exact instructions.

Comment: The figure and table environments are called "floats" because are designed to do just that... and most often the result in that way be much better that left static figures where do you think, using floats with [h]  or [H], or not using a float t all. Think twice if really the odd first page is a good place for a figure,  beside to a prominent title that leff  little space for  introductory text. May be could be really  better in the next even/odd pages when the lector have some idea of the chapter content and when the text have made already a reference to this figure.

Answer (score 2):

The figure is a floating object and LaTeX puts it where it fits best. If you want a figure to be at a specific postion you can use placement specifiers. For example with the package `float` you could say `\begin{figure}[H]`, then the figure is set at this position.

There is a very good answer which tells you everything about floating classes in latex:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/105976

Comment: it should be sufficient and less problematic `\begin{figure}[htb]` (without use of the package `float`).

Answer (score 2):

As an option to place figures at predetermined places in a document you could use a `minipage`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Title}    

    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{example image}
    \end{minipage}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```